# rewire() function on weighted graphs [igraph]

Tags: r, igraph

I know there is a topic on this already, but I tested the way they said in there and it did not work. 
I used rewire() in a weighted graph and the weight valeus were not transferred to the randomized graph.

```
>E(g)$weight
 [1] 0.7819693 0.7010414 0.7978514 0.7249481 0.8295889 0.9177085 0.6719408 0.6826897 0.8947611 0.7758267 0.9064469
[12] 0.8236665 0.7248115 0.7354699 0.7117599 0.7144824 0.7985431 0.6816086 0.6760310 0.8653517 0.7257873 0.8427769
[23] 0.7097822 0.6987642 0.8507158 0.9149504 0.8357126 0.9664860 0.8338331 0.7122003 0.7504638 0.6995491 0.8643859
[34] 0.8684505 0.8459311 0.7384111 0.7128058 0.7486494 0.8996575 0.8910186 0.7241546 0.7661719 0.7340575 0.8074797
[45] 0.9107946 0.8758860 0.9171899 0.7134565 0.7687820 0.8112824 0.8735326 0.6853292 0.7392045 0.6772795 0.7064094
[56] 0.7427759 0.8425719 0.9106251 0.8170464 0.8509228 0.7680797 0.7893403 0.8618796 0.7029206 0.6998891 0.9484128
[67] 0.7075254 0.8204882 0.7728777 0.6936007 0.6737966 0.8568317 0.7938365 0.7372963 0.7554374 0.7738223 0.7363732
[78] 0.6743658 0.7819415 0.7576451 0.8942746 0.7261943 0.7816130 0.8804163 0.8554249 0.7661933 0.7218388 0.8498031
[89] 0.8146921 0.7871279 0.8496426 0.9418762

>g2<-rewire(g,niter=1000)
> is.weighted(g2)
[1] TRUE

> E(g2)$weight
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[39] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[77] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

The igraph package is up to date and even with a random graph this happens. The gittered edges do not have weights

```
> g1<-graph.ring(100)
> plot(g1)
> E(g1)$weight<-seq_len(ecount(g1))
> g3<-rewire(g1,niter=100)
> is.weighted(g3)
[1] TRUE
> E(g3)$weight
[1]  3  8 11 23 24 27 28 45 60 61 65 69 71 78 84 91 93 98 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[38] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[75] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> g3<-rewire(g1,niter=10)
> E(g3)$weight
[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  22  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  32
[29]  34  36  38  41  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  67
[57]  68  69  71  72  73  74  76  77  78  79  80  81  83  84  85  86  87  89  90  91  92  94  98  99 100  NA  NA  NA
[85]  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Is it a bug or I am doing something wrong?
It does say it is weighted, but the valeus are all NA (at least the randomized ones).

```
> packageDescription("igraph")$Version
[1] "0.7.1"
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

EDIT:
Going further on this, how should the weights behave in this situation? For ex, if the edge weight A--B move to A--C, should its weight remain the same value? Or should it change (and, therefore, all others) so the graph.strength distribution remains the same?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, rather a lack of a feature - `rewire()` does not support edge weights. If you do not want to preserve the `graph.strength()` distribution of the edges, an easy workaround is to take `E(g1)$weight`, shuffle it, and re-assign the shuffled vector to `E(g3)$weight`.

Comment: I would like to maintain the 'graph.strength()' distribution. But with rewire thats impossible. Maintaining the 'degree' distribution will change 'graph.strength()' bc it changes the weights. Maintaining the same  'graph.strength()' distribution would require to change all the weights so it adapts to the new graph shape. but that adds even more problems. Just decided to use it unweighted all the way.

Comment: @Drizzt It is not very clear how to do the rewiring to preserve strengths. Adding weights suddenly makes the edges distinguishable: if we disconnect an edge from a vertex and reconnect another one instead, that preserves its degree, but not (usually) its strength.

Comment: @Szabolcs indeed. But there is a mathematical way to do rewiring and maintain the strengths. It is formalized in this math paper. It`s just beyond me to be able to code that http://www.uvm.edu/pdodds/files/papers/others/2006/serrano2006a.pdf      Also, this paper shows a nice application of it into networks https://www.nature.com/articles/srep07258

Comment: @CAOC Feel free to open a feature request for this (with link to the paper).

Comment: @Szabolcs You mean in the github of the package? or somewhere else?